# TYPO3 bring information to the JS environment

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I would like to bring information like page id and root page id into the JS environment.

I thinking of manipulating or generating a JS file via TypoScript, but I have no idea how.

I know I can achieve it via controller and route enhancer. But that would be very much code.

For security reasons, I don't want inline JS.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also prefer the approach of Wolffc to add the data as data-atrributes and fetch them in the js. I would suggest to pass the data as json-string. Then you only have to fetch one data variable in your js. I think thats the easiest and fastest way to pass variables to js.

But if you really want to go the TypoScript way. I would suggest to use a dynamic js-script.

Here is what to do:

First you need a USER_INT in your headerData. Add following TypoScript. Before check in your TypoScript-Object-Browser if 20 is occupied. If it is use a free number.
And of course adjust the VENDOR and ExtName to your extension.

```
page.headerData{
  20 = USER_INT
  20 {
    userFunc = VENDOR\ExtName\UserFunc\HeaderManipulator->addDynamicJs
  }
}
```

Then you will need the js template. Create a file in your extension.
/Resources/Private/Templates/Js/MyDynamicJs.js

```
let rootPageId = ###ROOT_PAGE_ID###;
let pageId = ###PAGE_ID###;

console.log('The Root-Page-Uid is: ' + rootPageId);
console.log('The Page-Uid is: ' + pageId);
```

At least you will need the User-Function to manipulate your dynamic js file. For that add following file to your extension.

Classes/UserFunc/HeaderManipulator.php

Adjust the VENDOR and ExtName in the namespace to fit your extension. And dont forget to adjust the extname in the file_get_contents path.

```
<?php
namespace VENDOR\ExtName\UserFunc;

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Core\Environment;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Http\ServerRequest;

class HeaderManipulator
{

    public function addDynamicJs($content, $conf, ServerRequest $request)
    {
        $rootPageId = $request->getAttribute("site")->getRootPageId();
        $pageId = $request->getAttribute("routing")->getPageId();

        // Replace ext_name with your extensions name
        $js = file_get_contents(Environment::getExtensionsPath() . '/ext_name/Resources/Private/Templates/Js/MyDynamicJs.js');
        $js = str_replace('###ROOT_PAGE_ID###', $rootPageId, $js);
        $js = str_replace('###PAGE_ID###', $pageId, $js);

        return "<script type='text/javascript'>$js</script>";
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to point out that this _does_ indeed create inline js which – for security reasons – OP does not want. Additionally, this adds a piece of uncacheable code to every page, which is not great for performance.

Answer (score 2):

We usually generate data attributes in the html. This way any js can acces these data attributes

Example `<html data-page-id="123">`

Answer (score 1):

The TYPO3 documentation actually gives an example of how to do this: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/12.4/en-us/Setup/Page/Index.html#jsfooterinline-array. No need to write any custom code. In v12 this script will either be moved into its own file, or the inline script tag will get a nonce which is allowed by the CSP:

```
page.jsInline {
  10 = TEXT
  10.stdWrap.dataWrap = window.pageId = {TSFE:id}; window.rootPage = {site:rootPageId}
}
```

If this is not an option, I would recommend adding `data-` attributes to e.g. the body tag and write some custom JS to read these.

Comment: Inline seems to mean that they put the JavaScript directly into a script tag

Answer (score 0):

In PHP:

```
echo "<script>sessionStorage.setItem('blup', '$bleep');</script>";
```

Or use typoscript for that with some wraps, also easy.

Then you can comfortable read out and then maybe delete immediately the session storage in js.

Secure it will never be, also not with the solutions mentioned below. If that is really important, then I advice you to put it in a PHP session, and make an Ajax call from js to decrypt it.

Comment: This information has not to be secure, but I don't want to allow script tags with inline js at all for security reasons.